# CORS response headers not shown when using @CrossOrigin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a basic GET endpoint, and attempted to allow CORS. However, the expected headers aren't returned in the response body, and I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong here.

GET method in my REST controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(
     allowCredentials = "true",
     origins = "*",
     allowedHeaders = {
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
             "Access-Control-Max-Age",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
             "Content-Type"})
public String test() {
    return "test";
}
```

When I send a request here, the response headers are as follows:

```
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 13 May 2019 19:33:11 GMT
```

I'm hoping to add the headers to this response, i.e.:

```
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 13 May 2019 19:33:11 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I see - these headers are only added for cross-origin requests. When I set the origin in the request headers, the response headers are added as expected.